# Sort array in Swift by last object

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I have an array that looks like this

```
[[AAA,BBB,CCC,3],
 [DDD,EEE,FFF,1],
 [GGG,HHH,III,2]]
```

I used the following Objective C code to sort the array by the last value in each string component:

```
NSSortDescriptor *aSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"@lastObject"                                                                           ascending:YES                                                                            comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
                if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue]) {
                    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
                }
                if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue]) {
                    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
                }
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
            }];

listNavData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[listNavDataUnsorted sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aSortDescriptor]]];
```

How do I do it in Swift? I tried to convert to code into Swift but failed. Is there a good way in Swift to sort an array based on the last component in the array components so that I have the following?

```
 [[DDD,EEE,FFF,1],
  [GGG,HHH,III,2],
  [AAA,BBB,CCC,3]]
```

Comment: Sorry. It is supposed to be an array of arrays. Corrected. Thanks for noticing it,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off of @MattLewin's detective work in interpreting the question, here is the Swift version using Array's `sort()` method:

```
let listNavDataUnsorted = [
    ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", 3],
    ["DDD", "EEE", "FFF", 1],
    ["GGG", "HHH", "III", 2]
]

let listNavDataSorted = listNavDataUnsorted.sort {($0.last as? Int) < ($1.last as? Int)}

print(listNavDataSorted) // [[DDD, EEE, FFF, 1], [GGG, HHH, III, 2], [AAA, BBB, CCC, 3]]
```

---

If instead your last item is a `String` and you want to sort by its integer value:

```
let listNavDataUnsorted = [
    ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "3"],
    ["DDD", "EEE", "FFF", "111"],
    ["GGG", "HHH", "III", "22"]
]

let listNavDataSorted = listNavDataUnsorted.sort {Int($0.last ?? "") < Int($1.last ?? "")}

print(listNavDataSorted) // [["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "3"], ["GGG", "HHH", "III", "22"], ["DDD", "EEE", "FFF", "111"]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I'm uncertain I fully understand the structure of your "listNavDataUnsorted" array, but the following Swift code duplicates the functionality you achieved with your Objective-C code.

```
let listNavDataUnsorted: NSArray = [
    ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", 3],
    ["DDD", "EEE", "FFF", 1],
    ["GGG", "HHH", "III", 2]
]

func compare(obj1: AnyObject, obj2: AnyObject) -> NSComparisonResult {
    if Int(obj1 as! NSNumber) > Int(obj2 as! NSNumber) {
        return NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending
    }
    else if Int(obj1 as! NSNumber) < Int(obj2 as! NSNumber) {
        return NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
    }
    else {
        return NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame
    }
}

let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "@lastObject", ascending: true, comparator: compare)   
let listNavDataSorted = listNavDataUnsorted.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([sortDescriptor])
```

I suspect there's a better way to accomplish this in Swift using the built-in Array's `sort(_:)`, but I haven't yet figured that out. I also haven't yet figured out the syntax for simply including the `compare` function in the `NSSortDescriptor()` call, though that is definitely possible in Swift.

Comment: Good job interpreting the question.  I provided the answer using Array's `sort()` method.

Comment: @vacawama Thanks very much for the compliment. Your answer is clearly the right way to do it in Swift. Really nice job.